# What are the effects of the "access commerce administration pages" permission

Tags: commerce

The SA-CONTRIB-2020-020 security patch was titled "Further restrict anonymous user access to anonymous orders."

Unfortunately it seems to have broken some sites I work on.  We are now seeing access denied errors on admin/commerce/orders/xxx for "semi-trusted" users who have permission "Default: Update orders".  For these sites the security patch was a non-back-compatible change and I have [raised an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3153884) for that.

The solution that worked for me is to grant the semi-trusted users the "access commerce administration pages" permission.

However I am nervous because this permission doesn't seem to have clear documentation.  I don't wish for these "semi-trusted" users to suddenly gain extra access that they should not have such as to edit products.

Please can anyone confirm the effects of this permission?  Does it do nothing alone and only work if other permissions are added?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report that must be reported to the issue queue on drupal.org to be fixed.

Comment: Agreed, please move this to the issue queue, though I'm not even sure it's a bug so much as a feature or documentation request? Re: clearer communication, it's pretty common practice _not_ to be overly specific in SA's to protect users while their upgrades are pending.

Comment: That's fine I'm very happy to raise an issue thanks for the guidance on the appropriate approach.

Comment: OK I have raised an issue.  The remaining question still seems valid - "please can anyone confirm the effects of this permission".

Comment: You might consider rephrasing the question title, this maybe helps to get to the point more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it do nothing alone and only work if other permissions are added?

Currently, yes (although that could theoretically change in the future).

The permission is added to all HTML admin routes for the order entity type (add/edit/etc), and for admin overview pages, which essentially list sub-pages that the user has access to.

If the user doesn't have access to those sub-pages, all provided by separate permissions, they won't see the links, and won't be able to visit them. Similarly, if they don't have the correct entity access permission, they won't be able to perform the respective operation on the entity.